# jQuery creating a simple object, adding properties and accessing it

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
// jquery 2.1.3 imported

var testarray = [];

var newTAelement = TAelement( "rs5", "Thirteen", "13", "15", "14","11","99");

function TAelement(category, question, trueanswer, c1, c2, c3, c4 )
{
    this.category = category;
    this.question = question;
    this.trueanswer = trueanswer;
    this.c1 = c1;
    this.c2 = c2;
    this.c3 = c3;
    this.c4 = c4;
}

testarray.push(newTAelement);

elementextracted = testarray[0];

alert(elementextracted.category);
```

I want to create the object that has the above properties

I want to store the value named "rs5" in the "category" property

And then add it to the array named testarray

And then access it.

I want to see the alert that says "rs5" but I am not seeing it.

What did I do wrong?  Thanks a lot Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You called the constructor function as if it were a regular function. This meant that the default value of `this` was (in a browser, outside of strict mode) `window` and not a new object. It also means that the default return value was `undefined` instead of that new object.

To use it as a constructor you need to use [the `new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

```
var newTAelement = new TAelement( "rs5", "Thirteen", "13", "15", "14","11","99");
```

NB: This has nothing at all to do with jQuery, which you don't use anywhere in your code. It is core JavaScript.

Comment: I thought push() was a method available in jQuery?

Comment: @서지혜 — jQuery does not (as far as I know) provide a push method, and even if it did: you are calling it on an array and not a jQuery object.

Comment: You can use jQuery and javascript mixed, but this is pure Javascript.

Comment: @Mikey jQuery IS JavaScript. You don't mix them; they are the same (jQuery is implemented in pure JS.)

Comment: @Mathletics I know that jQuery is JS under the hood, but what I am trying to say: you can use both syntaxes mixed.